# What does the `.title` property in `NSMenu` exist for?

Tags: cocoa, nsmenu

I'm now building up a menu bar app in Cocoa, and uses `NSMenu` instance to assign to the `.menu` property of `NSStatusItem`. However, `NSMenu` is initiated by calling `NSMenu(title: )` class method, while I don't know where the `.title` property is used in my app.

I tried to click on the menu bar app to expand or click on the inner element of `NSMenu` (`NSMenuItem` instance). However, I wasn't able to find anything I specified as the `.title` property (`TITLE` in my case, just for the illustration purpose's only).

So what is the purpose of specifying `.title`? Where does it used in my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's used for Sub-Menus, like in your menu bar the "Edit" menu, which is a NSMenu.

[image: NSMenu Title]

Comment: Thanks. My app doesn't have any windows or Dock and hence it didn't display the menu.